# Using urllib/urllib2 get a session cookie and use it to login to a final page

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib, urllib2

I need to use urllib/urllib2 libraries to login to a first website to retrieve session cookie that will allow me to log in to the proper, final website. Using `requests` library is pretty straight forward (I did it to make sure I can actually access the website):

```
import requests
payload = {"userName": "username", "password": "password", "apiKey": "myApiKey"}
url = "https://sso.somewebsite.com/api/authenticateme"
session = requests.session()
r = session.post(url, payload)
# Now that I have a cookie I can actually access my final website
r2 = session.get("https://websiteineed.somewebsite.com")
```

I tried to replicate this behavior using urllib/urllib2 libraries but keep getting `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`:

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
values = {"userId": username , "password": password, "apiKey": apiKey}
url = 'https://sso.somewebsite.com/api/authenticateme'
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
req2 = urllib2.Request('https://download.somewebsite.com')
resp2 = urllib2.urlopen(req2)
```

I tried solutions I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854077/using-a-session-cookie-from-selenium-in-urllib2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189555/how-to-use-python-to-login-to-a-webpage-and-retrieve-cookies-for-later-usage) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164679/how-to-send-cookies-in-a-post-request-with-the-python-requests-library) but none of them worked for me... I would appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the 'final page' was rejecting the cookies is because Python was adding `'User-agent', 'Python-urllib/2.7'`to the header. After removing this element I was able to login to a website:

```
opener.addheaders.pop(0)
```